# Where is the PDF encryption key stored

Tags: encryption, key-management, file-encryption, decryption, pdf

Assuming you have the user protected PDF file. Using the password, the cryptographic key is generated and the file encrypted. Where is the key stored, is it on the RAM every time the file is opened?

Comment: @schroedor The linked-to answer doesn't seem to answer this question. The linked-to question has to do with whether the sender of a PDFs necessarily has access to the sendee's password in cleartext, since that is what the sendee subsequently uses to open the PDF (and so the linked question asks whether the remote sender has a stored copy of the sendee's password). This question seems to be more about where the encryption key generated from the password is stored locally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on either the PDF spec or PDF readers, but I would guess the encryption / decryption key for a cipher like AES is derived from the password using a Password-Based Key Derivation Function such as PBKDF2, and that the password and key are only held in memory long enough to decrypt the document. After that you can zero out both the password and the key and only keep the decrypted document in memory.

---

... some googling later ...

According to [this old article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt) describing the behaviour in PDF 1.3 (Acrobat 4.x -- 1999), it does seem to be the case that the content encryption key is derived on the fly from the password. I'm sure the ciphers and key lengths have since been updated to something more modern, but I would guess that the general scheme is the same.

> The encryption key is generated as follows:
>
> 1. Pad the user password out to 32 bytes, using a hardcoded
>    32-byte string:
>    28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00 4E 56 FF FA 01 08
>    2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C A9 FE 64 53 69 7A
>    If the user password is null, just use the entire padding
>    string.  (I.e., concatenate the user password and the padding
>    string and take the first 32 bytes.)
> 2. Append the hashed owner password (the /O entry above).
> 3. Append the permissions (the /P entry), treated as a four-byte
>    integer, LSB first.
> 4. Append the file identifier (the /ID entry from the trailer
>    dictionary).  This is an arbitrary string of bytes; Adobe
>    recommends that it be generated by MD5 hashing various pieces
>    of information about the document.
> 5. MD5 hash this string; the first 5 bytes of output are the
>    encryption key.  (This is a 40-bit key, presumably to meet US
>    export regulations.)

Comment: +1.  I'm not an expert on PDF standards either, but I sure hope this answer is correct.  It doesn't make sense that the key would be stored persistantly.  I would assume that it works similarly to the way openssl does AES encryption and key derivation (see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption).